# How to display relation table in php?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, yii2, database-connection, displayobject

How to display relation table in php using oracle 11g with index format

this is my code:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM HOTEL');
oci_execute($stid);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
    $id_hotel = $row['ID_HOTEL'];
    $nama = $row['NAMA_HOTEL'];
    $kamar = $row->KAMAR_ID['NAMA_KAMAR'];
    $harga = $row['HARGA'];
    $gambar = $row['GAMBAR'];
    $lat = $row['LAT'];
    $lng = $row['LNG'];

    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng, '<b><img src=http://localhost/hotel/common/uploads/hotel/$gambar width=85 height=85></img></b> <p><b>$nama</b> - <b>$kamar</b></p> <b>Rp.$harga</b> <p><a href=index.php?r=catalog%2Fview&id=$id_hotel class=button_maps>Lihat Hotel</a></p>');\n");
}

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to join two tables?  How to create objects from your query?

Comment: You should use ActiveRecord .. and Yii2 Widget .. try explain better you need ..

Comment: yes, how to join two tables @axlj